# Read a csv file from blob storage and append data in that csv file by trigger azure function app

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

After HTTP trigger, I want to read .csv file from blob storage and append new data in that file. and want to save data in .csv format to blob storage. Please help me out.....

```
def upload_file(df):
 ACCOUNT_NAME = 'Name'
 ACCOUNT_KEY = 'key'
 #CONTAINER_NAME = 'container_name'
 block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=ACCOUNT_KEY)

 scriptpath=os.path.abspath('__file__')
 scriptdir=os.path.dirname(scriptpath)
 file_path=os.path.join(scriptdir,'output.csv')

 df.to_csv(file_path,index=False)

 block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
        'microbes',
        'output.csv',
        file_path,
        content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/CSV')
                )
upload_file(df)
```

my problem is after appending data, I have to save that data to blob storage. So that, I have to save all data in csv file but the above 500 internal server error comes.

Answer (score 1):

Try code below.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, BlobType
try:
    connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=httpsxxxxxxcore.windows.net"
    container_name = "xxx"
    blob_name = "xxx"
    data1 = "\n1,2,3"
    data = str.encode(data1)
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    print("length of data is "+str(len(data)))
    blob_client.append_block(data,length=len(data))
except:
    connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=httpsxxxxxxcore.windows.net"
    container_name = "xxx"
    blob_name = "xxx"
    data1 = "test1,test2,test3"
    data = str.encode(data1)
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    print("length of data is "+str(len(data)))
    blob_client.upload_blob(data,blob_type=BlobType.AppendBlob)
```

Comment: I'm able to upload data my local machine but when i deploy my code in azure function after hit my trigger then file do not upload